# How Can I Capture Mouse Coordinate on PictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I am new with c#. I have a image on picturebox, i would like to draw a rectangle on the image to capture X,Y coordinate and width/height of the rectangle that i will draw (against the image on picturebox). i know i must do something on pictureBox1_MouseEnter..etc. but i don't know where to start.

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Rectangle Rect = RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);
    }
```

I would appreciated if any one can give me sample code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't want to use `MouseEnter` at all. You want to use `MouseDown`, because you don't want to start tracking the rectangle the user draws until after they *click* the mouse button.

So in the [`MouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx) event handler method, save the current coordinates of the cursor. This is the starting position of the rectangle, point (X, Y).

```
private Point initialMousePos;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.initialMousePos = e.Location;
}
```

And then, in the [`MouseUp` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup.aspx), which is raised when the user stops dragging and releases the mouse button, you want to save the final ending point of the mouse cursor, and combine that with the initial starting point to build a rectangle. The easiest way to build such a rectangle is using the [`FromLTRB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.fromltrb.aspx) static method of the [`Rectangle` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx):

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Save the final position of the mouse
    Point finalMousePos = e.Location;

    // Create the rectangle from the two points
    Rectangle drawnRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(
                                             this.initialMousePos.X,
                                             this.initialMousePos.Y,
                                             finalMousePos.X,
                                             finalMousePos.Y);

    // Do whatever you want with the rectangle here
    // ...
}
```

You probably want to combine this with some painting code in the [`MouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx) event handler method to give the user a *visual* indication of the rectangle that they're drawing while they're drawing it.

The *right* way to do this is to handle the [`MouseMove` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx) to get the current position of the mouse, and then call the `Invalidate` method, which will raise the [`Paint` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx). All of your painting code should be in the `Paint` event handler. This is a better approach than the one taken by a lot of samples you find on the web, where you'll see something like `CreateGraphics` called inside of the `MouseMove` event handler method. Avoid that, if possible.

Sample implementation:

```
private Point currentMousePos;

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Save the current position of the mouse
    currentMousePos = e.Location;

    // Force the picture box to be repainted
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a pen object that we'll use to draw
    // (change these parameters to make it any color and size you want)
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3.0F))
    {
        // Create a rectangle with the initial cursor location as the upper-left
        // point, and the current cursor location as the bottom-right point
        Rectangle currentRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(
                                                   this.initialMousePos.X,
                                                   this.initialMousePos.Y,
                                                   currentMousePos.X,
                                                   currentMousePos.Y);

        // Draw the rectangle
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, currentRect);
    }
}
```

A couple of things to note about this code if you've never done any type of drawing before. The first thing is that I've wrapped the creation of a [`Pen` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.aspx) (which we use to do the actual drawing) in a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). This is good general practice any time you create an object that implements the [`IDisposable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), such as brushes and pens, to prevent a memory leak in your application.

Also, the `PaintEventArgs` provide us with an instance of the [`Graphics` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx), which encapsulates all of the basic drawing functionality in a .NET application. All you have to do is call methods like `DrawRectangle` or `DrawImage` on that class instance, passing in the appropriate objects as parameters, and all the drawing gets done for you automatically. Simple enough, right?

And finally, notice that we've done exactly the same thing here to create a rectangle as we ultimately do in the `MouseUp` event handler method. That makes sense, because we just want the instantaneous size of the rectangle while the user is creating it.

Comment: thanks Cody, your code works fine, would you mind to give me quick sample for painting ?

Comment: @Kelly: Updated with a painting sample. Not sure how familiar you are with this type of thing in the .NET world, so I tried to explain it as well as possible. Please leave a comment if you have any more questions!